# Can arcobjects validate topology globally

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, topology

I want to develop a function which allow user to validate a topology in the whole map wide. But from what I searching from internet, to validate a topology, a dirty area (polygon) must be defined, does it mean that I cannot validate the topology globally?

I am using vs 2012 (vb.net) and ArcObjects 10.2.1. Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually had a go at using Topology in ArcMap? You'll need at least an _ArcEditor_ license but if you have a play with that you can validate topology for the current screen or whole dataset. So based on that I would say Yes it can validate globally.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, you are right, in fact I need to validate the whole dataset, but the function is provided in ArcMap customized tool. I searched the internet but unfortunately failed to find a proper instruction on it. If possible, would you please advise me on it? thanks.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000nw000000

Comment: @lcoursey, thank you. But the link you provide is using python, I am now using ArcObjects.

Comment: @user30643 Just execute that tool using geoprocessing: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000